# Spark DataFrame turns empty after writing to table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm having some concerns regarding the behaviour of dataframes after writing them to Hive tables.

*Context*:
I run a Spark Scala (version 2.2.0.2.6.4.105-1) job through `spark-submit` in my production environment, which has Hadoop 2. 
I do multiple computations and store some intermediate data to Hive ORC tables; after storing a table, I need to re-use the dataframe to compute a new dataframe to be stored in another Hive ORC table.

E.g.:

```scala
// dataframe with ~10 million record
val df = prev_df.filter(some_filters)

val df_temp_table_name = "temp_table"
val df_table_name = "table"

sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true")
sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict")
df.createOrReplaceTempView(df_temp_table_name)
sql(s"""INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE $df_table_name PARTITION(partition_timestamp)  
      SELECT * FROM  $df_temp_table_name """)
```

These steps always work and the table is properly populated with the correct data and partitions.

After this, I need to use the just computed dataframe (`df`) to update another table. So I query the table to be updated into dataframe `df2`, then I join `df` with `df2`, and the result of the join needs to overwrite the table of `df2` (a plain, non-partitioned table).

```scala
val table_name_to_be_updated = "table2"

// Query the table to be updated
val df2 = sql(table_name_to_be_updated)

val df3 = df.join(df2).filter(some_filters).withColumn(something)

val temp = "temp_table2"

df3.createOrReplaceTempView(temp)
sql(s"""INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE $table_name_to_be_updated   
      SELECT * FROM  $temp """)
```

At this point, `df3` is always found empty, so the resulting Hive table is always empty as well. This happens also when I `.persist()` it to keep it in memory.

When testing with `spark-shell`, I have never encountered the issue. This happens only when the flow is scheduled in `cluster-mode` under Oozie.

What do you think might be the issue? Do you have any advice on approaching a problem like this with efficient memory usage?

I don't understand if it's the first `df` that turns empty after writing to a table, or if the issue is because I first query and then try to overwrite the same table.

Thank you very much in advance and have a great day!

**Edit:**

Previously, `df` was computed in an individual script and then inserted into its respective table. On a second script, that table was queried into a new variable `df`; then the table_to_be_updated was also queried and stored into a variable `old_df2` let's say. The two were then joined and computed upon in a new variable `df3`, that was then inserted with overwrite into the table_to_be_updated.

Comment: This is because you are reading & overwriting in same table.

Comment: @Srinivas: thanks for the reply. I have an observation though (to be added in the original question): previously, I computed `df` in an invidual script, then in a second script i was querying the respective `df` table and loading the current table to be updated (still via sql query), then joining the two and doing some other computations in a new variable, finally inserting the new dataframe with overwrite into the table to be updated - and it worked.

Comment: Why do you focus on `df`? You have proof that it is non-empty earlier in the program. It is much more likely that your `df2` turns out empty, or that the JOIN returns no match. Just do some basic debugging e.g. compute row counts, output some samples of key values (and key column types), etc